# How to configure arabic language POS tagging in stanfordNLP

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I have arabic POS Tagger libs. I am able to run it for English. But i do not find any configuration options for setting arabic Tagger or enable arabic POS tagging.
Please help.

Comment: Maybe there's simply no model available, because nobody has created one. See http://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.5.3/manual/opennlp.html#tools.postagger.training for how to create your own model, if you have annotated input.

Answer (score 3):

you can download the Arabic model from http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml
- choose full version , it works well :)